# Writing pandas dataframe to remote mysql using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a situation, where I want to write the dataframe  ex: **store_dataframe**
to remote mysql database.
**store_dataframe** contains around 15 columns and 200000 rows. I am using pandas to create this dataframe.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
```

My DB connection looks like

```
def db_connection():
    dbServer='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
    dbPass='xxx'
    dbSchema='accounts'
    dbUser='xxx'
    db=dbapi.connect(host=dbServer,db=dbSchema,user=dbUser,passwd=dbPass)
    return db
```

I am writing this data to remote mysql database using following lines of code.

```
store_dataframe = getthedataframe()
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://xxx:xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/merchant', echo=False)
res.to_sql(name='store_dataframe', con=engine, if_exists = 'replace', index=False,chunksize=5000)
db.commit()
```

**Issue**:
I am not able to **write** the dataframe to db **unless I restart the database** .

Its weird to restart the database every time I want to write this. What mistake I am making?

P.S  : does not throw any error,the program hangs/doesn't respond.

**My application resides in one system which connects to mysql in another system**

Comment: What do you mean exactly with restarting the database? What error do you get if you do not do this? What is `db_connection` used for? (it's not used in the code snippet below, as the `engine` is used for the connection with the database)

Comment: sudo service restart mysql in the remote machine.    Yes you are right about db_connection. I mentioned as I am doing     db.commit()
in  my snippet.

Comment: My application resides in one system which connects to mysql in another system

Comment: `db.commit()` should normally not be necessary (the engine takes care of that) Did you notice this was needed?

Comment: yes  engine takes care of that. But getting rid of db.commit() still doesnt solve my problem.

Comment: After writing the dataframe, can you read it? Or execute other commands?

Comment: I would assume there is another connection holding a lock on the table. Try `SHOW OPEN TABLES`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-open-tables.html

Comment: @joris : yes I can read it and execute all kinds of sql queries

Comment: @DavidMaust I executed  SHOW OPEN TABLES FROM accounts.  in_use and name_locked corresponding to the table store_dataframe are both set to 0.  this means  there is no lock on it